# Android Cursor Adapter for Custom ListView Layout - Null Pointer Exception Error

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

First post on this site, so forgive me my sins. I am attempting to create a custom ListView layout that is populated by fields from my SQLite Database Adapter class. Below is the method I tried to use for this, and it is called in the onCreate method of its class, as well as the onClick method of a button to save to the Database:

```java
//Method to re-populate custom list view songlist_layout when a new entry is added
    private void populateSongList() {

        //Cursor to navigate through records of the database
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

        //Need two arrays to work with the Cursor. First is from field names
        String [] fromFieldNames = new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, 
                                                 DBAdapter.KEY_SONGTITLE, 
                                                 DBAdapter.KEY_SONGDURATION};

        //Second is int array
        int [] toViewIDs = new int [] {R.id.textViewSongNumber, R.id.textViewSongName, 
                                       R.id.textViewSongDuration};

        //Cursor Adapter Object
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), 
                      R.layout.songlist_layout, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs,0);

        //Need to grab ListView from activity_add_song to set the adapter to it
        ListView songList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.songsListView);
        songList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
    }
```

```java
 //Method to handle the click event of the Save button, adding the data into the database
    public void onClickSaveSong (View v) {

        //Song Title and duration are essential fields, so we want to check if they 
        //     have text before saving to the database
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(etSongTitle.getText().toString()) && 
           !TextUtils.isEmpty(etSongDuration.getText().toString())) {

            myDb.insertRow(etSongTitle.getText().toString(), 
                           etSongKey.getText().toString(), 
                           etSongTuning.getText().toString(),
                           etSongDuration.getText().toString());

            //Pop-up to inform user the Data has been saved
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Song Added!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }//if

        //Otherwise a pop-up to tell the user to enter the essential info
        else {Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Title and Duration", 
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

        //Call to repopulate songs ListView
        populateSongList();

    }//onClickSaveSong()
```

The custom XML Layout for the ListView contains three TextViews to hold the songNumber, the songName and the songDuration:

```xml
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewSongNumber"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewSongName"
        android:paddingRight="60dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewSongDuration"
        android:paddingRight="70dp"/>
```

I have read elsewhere that the problem could be because the ListView is grabbing from the wrong ListView ID 
`ListView songList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.songsListView);`
However comparing it to the XML Layout for the ListView, I don't see how this would be the case:

```xml
<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/songsListView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addSongButton" />
```

Finally, the logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blob.gigstrofinal/com.blob.gigstrofinal.AddSong}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.blob.gigstrofinal.AddSong.populateSongList(AddSong.java:121)
            at com.blob.gigstrofinal.AddSong.onCreate(AddSong.java:45)
```

I cannot figure this out. I haven't been using Android for long, and a lot of this is over my head, so I would appreciate any help at all on this matter. The App is for a University Project, and it is due next week!

EDIT: I forgot to specify, the Null Pointer Exception is pointing to line 121 of AddSong.java which is: `songList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);`

I am calling the `populateSongList()`method from the onCreate method in the AddSong class:

```java
public class AddSong extends Activity {

    //Declare Database Adapter
    DBAdapter myDb;

    //Declare EditText objects to be used for each field in the SQLite Database
    EditText etSongTitle;
    EditText etSongKey;
    EditText etSongTuning;
    EditText etSongDuration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_song);


        //Initialise EditText objects by assigning them to the corresponding ID
        etSongTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSongTitle);
        etSongKey = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSongKey);
        etSongTuning = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSongTuning);
        etSongDuration = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSongDuration);

        //Call method to open Database
        openDB();
        //Call to populate songs ListView
        populateSongList();
    }
```

and again for the onClickSaveSong method of AddSong.java (see second code snippet of original post.

EDIT2: The full contents of activity_add_song.xml:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.blob.gigstrofinal.AddSong"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tvSongTitle"
        android:id="@+id/songTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/songTitle"
        android:id="@+id/editSongTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:editable="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:background="#e6e6e6"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary3"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tvKey"
        android:id="@+id/songKey"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary2"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editSongTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editSongKey"
        android:layout_below="@+id/songKey"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editSongTitle"
        android:background="#e6e6e6"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tvTuning"
        android:id="@+id/songTuning"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary2"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editSongKey"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editSongTuning"
        android:layout_below="@+id/songTuning"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editSongKey"
        android:background="#e6e6e6"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary3"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tvDuration"
        android:id="@+id/songDuration"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary2"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editSongTuning"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editSongDuration"
        android:layout_below="@+id/songDuration"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editSongTuning"
        android:background="#e6e6e6"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary3"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tvLyrics"
        android:id="@+id/songLyrics"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editSongDuration"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editSongLyrics"
        android:layout_below="@+id/songLyrics"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editSongDuration"
        android:background="#e6e6e6"
        android:layout_above="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary3"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:text="@string/buttonSaveText"

        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:onClick="onClickSaveSong"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:text="@string/backButtonText"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickBack"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It is perhaps worth mentioning that the ListView itself is not located in Activity_add_song, it is in another Activity activity_songs. Would that cause a null pointer exception?

Comment: what is line 121 of AddSong.java?

Comment: `songList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);` is on line 121. It uses the ListView grabbed from my custom XML layout and passes in the cursor adapter 'myCursorAdapter'.

Comment: where are you calling populateSongList() from? please share your onCreate code

Comment: Made an edit there, hopefully that makes things a little clearer.

Comment: Can you show the full contents of activity_add_song.xml?

Comment: Included activity_add_song.xml in Edit 2. Would the fact that the ListView I am trying to populate is in a different Activity?

Comment: Well there's your problem.  No ListView in the xml layout for this Activity.  If this ListView is in a different Activity, you will need to move all code dealing with the ListView to that other Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the ListView is not in the layout xml that you're inflating in this Activity.

When you call this in onCreate():

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_song);
```

You're inflating the activity_add_song.xml layout xml to the current Window.

Then when you call:

```
ListView songList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.songsListView);
```

It's looking at the currently inflated layout for a ListView with ID songsListView.  Since there is no songsListView in the currently inflated layout (activity_add_song.xml), it will be null.

Move all code dealing with `songsListView` to the Activity that inflates the layout with the ListView.

Comment: Ah I understand! However, what I want to have happen is that when the user fills in the EditTexts in activity_add_song and clicks the save Button, the onClickSaveButton is called, which creates a new row in a database using my DBAdapter class and then re-populates the ListView by calling populateSongList() again. How would I accomplish this if I moved the method and all the other code relating to songsListView over? Hopefully I've articulated that clearly enough, and sorry for the terrible format! Thanks again for your comment

Comment: You can add data to the database from anywhere in your app.  The code dealing with the ListView, however, needs to stay contained in the Activity that displays it.

Comment: I moved all the code over and it worked! Thanks Daniel, I owe you a pint! One more question for you. Would it be possible to have a button in my custom XML layout `songlist_layout` for each record, that deletes that specific record from the database?

Comment: @savien yes you could do that, but a contextual action bar is the Android way to do it.  Long press of a row brings up a contextual action bar with a delete icon.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `populateSongList()` after `setContentView()`.

And please be more specific about where the line 121 is.

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.blob.gigstrofinal.AddSong.populateSongList(AddSong.java:121)`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even realise myself it was pointing to 121. `songList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);` is at line 121.

Comment: `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_song);
       
        //Call method to open Database
        openDB();
        //Call to populate songs ListView
        populateSongList();
    }` 



`populateSongList();` is called after `setContentView()`

Comment: Which means the ListView songsListView is null. Make sure you are inflating the correct layout file and make the call after setContentView is called.

Comment: When you say inflating, do you mean when I'm passing the layout in as a parameter to create a new SimpleCursorAdapter in the line: 

`myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.songs_layout, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs,0);`

Or do you meant something else entirely? I have checked, and that should be the correct layout file. It's the custom xml layout that I want to use to set to the ListView from my other Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Since line 121 is this:

```
songList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

and that is where you are getting null, then either songList or myCursorAdapter is null. myCursorAdapter is clearly not null, so you likely have the wrong name for your `findViewById` method in this line:

```
ListView songList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.songsListView);
```

Check that the listview is actually called "songsListView" in your XML - it probably isn't.

Comment: I have triple checked, and even created a new custom xml layout file with different IDs and changed the IDs in my method accordingly, but I still get the same null pointer error. Can you think of any other reason why this is happening? Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Your `activity_add_song.xml` should contain the ListView, **which is missing in your code.**

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/songsListView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/addSongButton" />
```

and `R.layout.songlist_layout` should contain the layout for each row

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewSongNumber"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewSongName"
    android:paddingRight="60dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewSongDuration"
    android:paddingRight="70dp"/>
```